# AutoFilter.Range.Copy Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter one worksheet using AutoFilter then copy the filtered content to another worksheet using AutoFilter.Range.Copy. However, when I run the code, an error message pops up saying

> object variable or With block variable not set.

My code is as below:

```
Sub Macro_CreateNewSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim report As Workbook
Set report = ActiveWorkbook

NowMonth = MonthName(Month(Now), True)
Nowday = Day(Now)

Set rp = report.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), 
Type:=xlWorksheet)
rp.Name = NowMonth & " " & (Nowday - 6) & "-" & Nowday

Dim origin As Workbook
Set origin = Workbooks.Open("My Directory")

Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String
EndDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
StartDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -6, EndDate), "mm/dd/yy")

Set WS1 = origin.Worksheets("ABS")
Set cl = report.Worksheets("Calculation")

With WS1
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
.AutoFilter.Range.Copy cl.Cells(1, 1)
.ShowAllData
End With

End Sub
```

When I try to debug the error, the highlighted sentence is

```
.AutoFilter.Range.Copy cl.Cells(1, 1)
```

I am not very familiar with VBA, please help me figure out the problem here.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which line is highlighted when the error occurs.

Comment: 1. `Set origin = Workbooks.Open("My Directory")` hope you have the full path, file name, and extension.  2. `StartDate = DateAdd("d", -6, EndDate)` should be `StartDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -6, Date), "mm/dd/yy")`

Comment: @braX, please see update, thank you!

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes, I was using the full path. And thank you for the format correction.

Comment: *I am not very familiar with VBA* Then why are you writing this code?

Comment: @JohnyL Because I am asked to.